# Error in php script insert don't work

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to insert the word 'Uurloon' in my database... But I got an error

Session is started, I included header.php where session is started

```
<?php

// UREN
 $con=mysqli_connect("d","d","d","d");
 // Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

 // escape variables for security
  $omschrijving = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['omschrijving']);

  $sql=("UPDATE users (uurloon,)
 VALUES ( '$omschrijving') WHERE user_id = ".$_SESSION['user_id']." ");

 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
 <!--
window.location = "index.php"
//-->
 </script>';

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I receive the following error:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your    MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(uurloon,) VALUES ( 'haa',) WHERE user_id =1' at line 1

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

I cant see my mistake or something

Connecting is fine but the insert... I got troubles

Comment: Remove the comma after urloon

Comment: Is that your actual code? Your error message also shows there is a comma after your value (`haa`), your posted code, however, does not reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if($_POST) {
    if(!empty($_POST['omschrijving']) {
//uren 

$connect = mysqli_connect("d","d","d","d");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$omschrijving = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['omschrijving']);
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$query = "UPDATE `users` SET `uurloon` = '$omschrijving' WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id'"; //Update query
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`uurloon`) VALUES ('$omschrijving')"; //Insert query

if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "index.php"
//-->
</script>';
}}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Je haalt een ***update*** query en een ***insert*** query door elkaar. Ik ga ervan uit dat je hier een update query nodig bent.

You are mixing an update and insert query. I guess you need an update query for this

***UPDATE*** probeer dit eens (try this):

```
$query = "UPDATE `users` SET `some_column` = 'uurloon' WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id'"; //This will put the word "uurloon" in some_column
```

A beter way to go to another page:

```
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
```

In a function:

```
to($url) {
   header('Location: ' . $url);
   exit();
}
```

Comment: +1 for the bilingual explanation (although I only understood the second bit).

Comment: Dank je wel voor je reactie! Ik heb dit geprobeerd en idd hij linkt me nu door en geeft geen fouten aan.. maar hij veranderd niet in mijn database..

Thank you for your reaction! I did it what you sayd in that reaction.. and yes he rederict me to index.php and give no more errors.. but he don't update in the sql table

Comment: @AbbedeVries added another query to try. nog een query toegevoegd

Comment: Error: Unknown column 'some_column' in 'field list'

Comment: @AbbedeVries you have to change the name of it to the column you want. Je moet de naam aanpassen naar de naam van de kolom waar uurloon in moet

Comment: Oke! ik heb dat geprobeerd en helaas hij update nog steeds de colum uurloon niet

Comment: @AbbedeVries hoe heet de kolom en wat moet er in komen?

Comment: @SuperDj die heet uurloon en de variable $omschrijving moet er in komen

Comment: @AbbedeVries Als je die 2 `if statements` probeert krijg je dan ook een fout / witte pagina oid.

Comment: @SuperDjNope niks... linkt gwn weer door naar index.php

Answer (score 0):

`$sql=("UPDATE users (uurloon,)` remove the comma after uurloon

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to **INSERT** you need to use **INSERT** command, not UPDATE:

```
$sql=("INSERT INTO users (uurloon) VALUES ('$omschrijving')");
```

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE user_id = 1' at line 2

ok thnx for all u reactions 

I tryed now i got a new error ^^

Comment: @abbedeVries i have changed my post, check it.